# Wemos D1 mini (esp8266 12-F) does not respond to AT commands

Tags: esp8266, arduino-esp8266, esp8266wifi

I have been working for some months with these modules, but I have some major issues about them that I have never learned how to deal with.

Sometimes, my modules stop responding (I don't know the reason) so I flashed the firmware and everything workes another time.

Now, after one week the modules I'm using have stoped working (I have tested all the voltages and electrical stuff and it's correct). I have tryed to flash the modules but this didn't seem to work. The only thing I can recibe from the modules is that when I click the manual reset button, the modules sends WIFI DISCONNECTED (apart from lots of grabbage characters). I have testes all this in different baud rates, but I can only recive clear data when I'm at 115200 bauds.

Does someone have some Idea?

Comment: and what doesn't work? the AT firmware is set to 115200 baud at default yes.

Comment: @Juraj The module doesn't respond to me. I have tested and the module is working at the appropriate voltage and I have also checked the connections to see if I changed some wire or something. I have also tried to flash the firmware as you told me other time. The only thing that I recive is when I reset the module manually. If so, the module sends me grabagge characters and at the end it sends me "WIFI DISCONNECTED". I cannot interact with the module with any command, so I don't know what else to do. Thanks

Comment: do you send both line ends with the AT command?

Comment: @Juraj, yes, and at the default baud rate of 115200 bauds

Comment: @Juraj, I have been testing all the projects and the trouble was not into the wifi module, it was into the Arduino Uno. I replaced it and everything started running. But thanks for helping.